How do you repaint a RenderBox from a LeafRenderObjectWidget?
Is there a way to repaint the RenderBox of a LeafRenderObjectWidget with updated data, but without rebuilding the whole widget?
I.e. something similar to CustomPainter(repaint: someListenable).
How would you approach this requirement?
Any advise is welcome, Thank you.

see markNeedsPaint

@pskink Great! Thank you very much for the quick reply!

sure, your welcome
